# Как создать новый столбец на основе содержания другого?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, обработка-данных

Внутри df есть столбец `Дата_ТА_все`, который либо Nan, либо дата.
Мне нужно каким-то образом создать третий столбец `ТА_был`.

В столбце 'ТА_был' нужно:

- записать "0", если в столбце 'Дата_ТА_все' - Nan,
- записать "1", если в столбце 'Дата_ТА_все' - дата.

Подскажите, как правильно это можно сделать?

Пробовал через функцию lambda, но я не знаю каким общим признаком объединить дату в столбце 'Дата_ТА_все'.

```
     ID УЕ   Дата_ТА_все
0   2110453   2021-02-18
1   2109466   2021-02-06
2   2109467   2021-02-06
3   2109468   2021-02-06
4   2109410   2021-02-06
   ...  ... ...
94  2110959   2021-02-24
95  2110945   2021-02-24
96  2110945   2021-02-24
97  2110946   2021-02-24
98  2111034   2021-02-25
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [Series.notna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html):

```
df['ТА_был'] = df['Дата_ТА_все'].notna().astype('int8')
```

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо, мне это помогло!